# Margin problem on management menu?

Tags: admin-menu, admin-css

I'm developing a Wordpress site (www.costactiva.com). It's a multilingual site with around 15 languages at the end. I found this 'mistake?' in the Menus area:

[image]

When I have more languages than they fit in the left column, they start to disappear back the right column.

Could you please tell me which one of the ones of .css is the one I have to modify to put the appropiate margin to this ?

**NOTE:** The inspect link to the css says this:

> http://costactiva.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load=dashicons,admin-bar,wp-admin,buttons,wp-auth-check,wp-color-picker&ver=4.3.3

And doesn't give me a clue on which css modify...

Comment: Inspect the element and find the appropriate class/ID name

Comment: I did, but it doesn't say which .css to touch. It says:
http://costactiva.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load=dashicons,admin-bar,wp-admin,buttons,wp-auth-check,wp-color-picker&ver=4.3.3

And I'm not sure where to look at...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify Wordpress' admin CSS. Well, technically you could, but it'd just get overridden the next time you update Wordpress.

The solution to this is to add your own custom CSS file to override the parts you wish to.

In your theme's `functions.php`, you can add a new CSS file to be loaded only in the Wordpress admin:

```
add_action("admin_enqueue_scripts", "my_enqueue_scripts_admin");

function my_enqueue_scripts_admin(){
  wp_register_style("my-admin-css", get_template_directory_uri() . "/admin.css", array(), "1.0", "all");
  wp_enqueue_style("my-admin-css");
}
```

Then, create a file called `admin.css` in your theme's root directory. In here, you can add the CSS to directly target the relevant class or ID on the menu page.

In your case, it looks like `#menu-management-liquid` might be the ID you need to target. You could do `#menu-management-liquid { margin-left: 100px; }` to move it over a bit, or you could instead target the language list and limit it's width or make it wrap (I'd probably prefer this option - otherwise you could be moving the entire menu management section a long way over!)

Comment: You're welcome @Sonia! Glad it helped.